# Need Help to Add a domain with VPS

Tags: domain, vps, cname-record, a-record

I recently bought a VPS and installed LAMP & WordPress. All went ok and then I tried to add the VPS to my domain.  My domain is hosted with Yahoo. I added an A record with the IP address of my VPS.  But after 1 day I found it is not working. Then I tried to add a custom nameserver. I signed up for namecheap free dns. In free dns I added an A record with my VPS ip address and for CNAME I added the hostname VPS hostname.  Namecheap provided me some nameserver and I added it in my domain nameserver section. But it still isn't working.  Please help me add my VPS to my domain.

My VPS IP: 162.220.12.177
My Domain Name: shikkharthi.com

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have correctly added the Namecheap nameservers to your domain's record.

Namecheap's DNS servers seem to have a completely empty zone for your domain. This is, of course, a serious problem.

```
$ host -v -t soa shikkharthi.com freedns3.registrar-servers.com
Trying "shikkharthi.com"
Using domain server:
Name: freedns3.registrar-servers.com
Address: 67.228.228.217#53
Aliases: 

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43410
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;shikkharthi.com.               IN      SOA

Received 33 bytes from 67.228.228.217#53 in 97 ms
```

I think you should open a support ticket with Namecheap and provide them this information. This is pretty clearly their problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your A record is not setup correctly.

Here is the dig output for your domain:
    [root@zee ~]# dig shikkharthi.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> shikkharthi.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37859
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;shikkharthi.com.               IN      A

;; Query time: 244 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 30 19:23:00 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 33
```

If you have setup the A record correctly you should see it mapping with your VPS IP address e.g,

```
[root@zee ~]# dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31004
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.113.226
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.113.233
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.113.227

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 30 19:25:05 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 204
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try http://freedns.afraid.org/ very easy and very much reliable otherwise you can setup your name server on your VPS also.